# How to append render partial to the view class?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I create a type.js.erb in the views/posts/type.js.erb with the:

```
$('.more').on('click', function(){
    $('.posts').append("<%= render partial: 'type', locals: { count: 30 } %>");
})
```

And it prints in console the next errors:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://178.62.102.154/".

178.62.102.154/:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://178.62.102.154/assets/type.js.erb' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

jquery.js:4 Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://178.62.102.154/".
```

How can I fix it and can append it to the .more div?

**UPDATE**

index.html.erb => http://pastebin.com/jdRmDjDa

Posts_Controller => http://pastebin.com/HraLpeVg

_type.html.erb => http://pastebin.com/gmv0B15a

type.js.erb => I wrote it above

Comment: can you display the snippet of code for the `views` as well as the `controller`

Comment: @Finks I update my question. You can look

Answer (score 0):

there is a helper method escaoe_javascript for this purpose.
<%= escape_javascript(render 'form', :products => @products) %>
You don't have to mention locals just pass them directly

Answer (score 0):

It seems my hunch,the problem is in the method `type` in your controller:

```
def type
  render partial: "type", locals: { count: 30 }
end
```

What this does is that, you're trying to render an html page but rails expects you to render a javascript. Remove `render partial: "type", locals: { count: 30 }` and refactor `type.js.erb` to:

```
$('.more').on('click', function(){
  $('.posts').append("<%=j render 'type', count: 30 %>");
})
```

`j` is a shorthand method for `escape_javascript`. Try it out.

Comment: the same error here. On load the page in console appears `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html`

`Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type text/html`

Comment: Ok, how do you call `type` action? Are you using link? button in form to trigger that action? Did you put `remote: true` there?

Comment: please follow the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28322522/what-the-error-neterr-content-length-mismatch-means-in-rails?noredirect=1#comment44993536_28322522